# how to make a div_t operation into an int in c++

Tags: html, c++, arrays

Might be pretty simple but I am trying to get a remainder in c++. I am trying to use the div_t and perform that operation to get a remainder. Here is the code I am using.

```
div_t rb;
    rb = div(xx, 8);

    int rgtBbox = rb;
```

essentially I just need to know how to cast the rb into an int. the error I get back from visual studio is there is no conversion function from div_t to int.

just for more information here is the entire function.

```
bool Game::grid_place_meeting(int x, int y)
{

    int xx = x;
    int yy = y;

    //The players 'map' position
    div_t rb;
    rb = div(xx, 8);

    int rgtBbox = rb;

    div_t leftBbox;
    leftBbox = div(xx+8, 8);

    div_t botBbox;
    botBbox = div((yy), 8);

    div_t topBbox;
    topBbox = div((yy + 8), 8);


    //check for x_Meeting
    bool x_meeting = false;
    bool y_meeting = false;

    if( (map[rgtBbox][topBbox] != floor) || (map[leftBbox][topBbox]) != floor)
    {
        x_meeting = true;
    }

    if ((map[rgtBbox][botBbox] != floor) || (map[rgtBbox][botBbox]) != floor)
    {
        y_meeting = true;
    }

    return x_meeting || y_meeting;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `%`?

Comment: `rb.quot` and `rb.rem` return the quotient and remainder parts of it.

Answer (score 0):

`div` will provide the remainder, but it also provides the quotient. Since there are two numbers, which would be reasonable to expect from `int rgtBbox = div(xx, 8)`?

`div_t` takes care of that by bundling both remainder and quotient into one returnable object. [According to reputable documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div), `div_t` is defined as:

```
struct div_t 
{ 
    int quot; 
    int rem; 
};
```

So all that is needed is to access `rem`

```
int rgtBbox = rb.rem;
```

or alternately use the modulo operator:

```
int rgtBbox = xx % 8
```

Comment: AH cool. this is what i was looking for. I need the quotient not the remainder. thanks!